# Update autoincrement field to highest value + 1

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

How can I update an existing row's `id` (autoincrement) field to give it the value that would normally be automatically assigned to a new insert (i.e., highest id + 1)?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html states:

**"...You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers."**

But this doesn't appear to be true.  I've tried assigning a value of 0 and it does just that.. asigns a value of 0.

I've considered deleting and re-inserting the row but this seems messy.

Also tried:

```
UPDATE example_table
SET id = (SELECT id+1 FROM example_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE id = 1000;
```

Which returns the error: *You can't specify target table 'example_table' for update in FROM clause*

and:

```
UPDATE example_table SET id = max(id)+1 WHERE id = 1000;
```

Which returns the error: *Invalid use of group function*

This seems like it should be easy... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow using table being updated in a from clause.
you can have it as sub query

```
UPDATE example_table
     SET id= (SELECT maxId
              FROM (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS maxId
                    FROM example_table
                   ) t
              )
    WHERE id = 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks.. is that really that best way though?  A sub query within a sub query seems absurdly complex for such a simple task.

Comment: @billynoah, yes i agree, or you need to get the maxid in a variable and use it, but you need to both of them in a transaction.

Comment: I tried your suggestion just now and get the error ***Every derived table must have its own alias***

Comment: @billynoah, edited, need to give alias name for the sub query

Comment: Thanks.. i just did the same thing and it works.  Still interested in a cleaner solution though.  It seems like I should just be able to assign NULL or 0 to autoincrement to achieve this as stated in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with a `join`:

```
UPDATE example_table CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 as nextid
        FROM example_table
       ) maxet
    SET id = maxet.nextid
    WHERE id = 1000;
```